# What is making my file so heavy?

Tags: rendering

Even if I hide almost everything in the scene, my computer cannot begin to render. I left it to render over night and it was still stuck on 0% in the morning. If anyone could check out my file I would really appreciate it!

(I tried reducing the render passes to 32 and reducing light bounces to 4, no dice).

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pr1FdO461RaFQDsTo5klWofKiG31IbMe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Things that are hidden in the scene still appear in the render. To truly remove them from the render process, move them all to a separate collection, then disable (not hide) the collection by unchecking the check box.

Comment: Usually when the rendering fails there is message in the top left of the render window. What is displayed there when you try to render ?

Comment: @Gorgious no error message!

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thanks! But moved almost all to another collection and still having the same issue

Comment: I think it has to do with your procedural textures and the overall detail of your mesh - attempting to render it quickly ate up all 32gb of my ram, and tried to start paging. I stopped it there. Not sure what's going on in your node groups but that will definitely contribute.. Also, your meshes seem enormously complex and many could  undergo significant remeshing/poly-reduction without losing any visual fidelity - is there some reason they're that detailed?

Answer (score 5):

Your file is 380 MB heavy.  One part is that you have high poly objects with 2 UV maps for each object. That's about 150 MB. You can delete the UV maps to save space. There are also *Custom Split Normals Data*, about 20 MB. Then, it's still 215 MB big, but I'm not sure why Blender still needs that many bytes...?

**Why it doesn't render**

As already mentioned you have a few **high poly objects** in your scene. Each of these objects has something like 257,000 vertices, 607,000 edges, 350,000 faces - and they have a ***Subdivision Surface* modifier, Viewport level: 0, Render level: 1**. That's the problem.

If you render this, the modifier kicks in and adds some geometry... 1.2 million vertices, 2.4 million edges, 1.2 million faces for one object. This is multiplied by the number of objects and ... good night ;-)

**Solution:** Remove the modifiers and it will render fine.

To decrease the render time you can use the default `128` samples, tick `[X]` *Adaptive Sampling*, and use the denoiser in the compositor.

Also, these objects in the background can be rather low-poly. 5k or 10k vertices with a bump/normal map should do the trick. No need for 257k vertices.

[image: render result]
<sup>128 samples, AA, denoiser node, 20 minutes render time (CPU), 1.5GB mem peak</sup>